# Google Earth vs Google Maps for low bandwidth users

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I am preparing to develop a mapping app that places semi-transparent tiled images over ocean to show weekly output from satellite data passed through an algorithm. I have worked with Maps placing landmarks before using custom Javascript and have created/modified simple KML files. Some of my users have advised they are on low-bandwidth connections (i.e. Pacific islands) of about 256Kbit.

For these folks, which is going to give better performance? I imagine that GE as a thick client will be generally more responsive and I have heard that some data can be cached, but I also think that Google Maps is likely very highly optimised for performance and is obviously a thin (browser) client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option, why not just provide KML files and let the users use whatever KML-consuming client they wish? That way, you could develop for Google Maps, but if they want to use Google Earth or some other desktop client that may aggressively cache or simply provide map data on-disk, they can use your KML data as an overlay.

Comment: I guess I'm seeing this from the client's perspective. They are not tech-savvy and will need advice as to 'the way' to do things with limited bandwidth. I have run some GE KML through Google Maps but the result didn't look too pretty. Is this a common way to do both GE and Maps?

Comment: Well, I would imagine that Maps might have some trouble with some of the more advanced features available in the KML spec... but for simple things like image overlays, polygon outlines, etc. it really should be fine as long as your geometry isn't to complex. If it's not unreasonable to request your clients to use Google Earth (which is a large download in and of it self initially), try benchmarking it. Limit your bandwidth to 256kbps and see how usable your app is, **then** start tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

You could put expires headers on you kml to enable caching on the browser and as a plus you can implement some kind of around the viewport precaching at connection idle time so they can experience a better performance.